# Remove WIFI-Network as device owner

Tags: java, android, wifi, nfc

I'm using nfc provisioning to deploy my device owner app. What I want now is to remove/forget the wifi network from the device that is used during the provision (forever). Is this possible?

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone in the future:

It's actually pretty easy. `WifiManager.removeNetwork(int netId)` does the work for you when you're the device owner!